# Trouble looping through data in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am using javaScript to go through 149 input type number fields and I am having problems getting it to work. I have conditions set that if the value of those number fields are negative, float, or 0 it will return an error message using

alert(" Error Message");

I am iterating through my input type's through a for loop like the following

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var i; var x = 0; var s; var val; var test; 
for (i = 1; i < 150; i++) {
  s = '' + i; //converts i into string

  val = document.getElementById(s).value; //Puts string value into val
  test = +val; //Converts val into number
//Error Checking
}
```

I have tried this code on smaller input type = number fields (such as 10), and all of my error flags work, but whenever I use my needed number 149 (set to 150 because I want it to do one less than 150) I do not receive any error messages or activity from my funciton.

Comment: WoW! 149 input fields?

Comment: *"but whenever I use my needed number 149 ...I do not receive any error messages or activity from my function."* Do you have 149 actual inputs on the page?

Comment: Show us your HTML.

Comment: [pict](https://i.gyazo.com/7de34ec45bad27cdbae81d846515f8b6.png) This is basically what it looks like. Just displaying data from a database and allowing someone to update a quantity that they would like to have ordered for any of the products.

Comment: @zer00ne yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example .

```js
//For Demo Puropse 
for(i=1;i<300;i++){
var node = document.createElement("input");
node.id=i
node.value=i
  document.getElementById("stage").appendChild(node)
}

function checkValues(){
  for(i=1;i<300;i++){
    elemValue = document.getElementById(i).value
    if(! isInteger(elemValue) || ! elemValue){
      alert("Error ! : " + elemValue + "@" + i)
      return;
    }
  }
  
  alert("Passed")
}

function isInteger(x) {
    return x % 1 === 0;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkValues()">Check</button>
<br/>
<div id="stage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my code. I am reading from a data base that I did not want to display the credentials too. In my code you will see a comment that has the comment question. Is there a way that I can just use php to get the product number and the quantity so that I can use it in form.php. It is a post method, but as the question says I am fairly new to this coding language. Hopefully this code snippet will tell you more about what I am actually trying to accomplish.

```
        <form action="form.php" method="post">


    <table cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Image</th> 
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    <!-- PHP LANGUAGE -->
    <?PHP
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM parts";
        $q = $conn->query($sql) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $conn->errorIndo()));

        while( $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

            echo '<tr>' .
                '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $row['weight'] . '</td>' . 
                '<td> <img src="' . $row[pictureURL] .'" alt="' . $row[number] . '" style="width:50px;height:50px;">' .
                '<td> <input type="number" id= "'. $row[number] . '"  value="0">' .
                '</td>' . '</tr>';
        }
        echo "</table>";

    ?> 
    </table> <br>



    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
    var i; var x = 0; var s; var val; var test; var array = [];
    $('form').submit(function(){{
        var value = $(this).val();

        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
          s = '' + i;  //stores i as string 
          //getsElement id val string and stores into val
          val = document.getElementById(s).value; 
          test = +val; //Converts string into tester int for error checking 

          if tester < 0 { alert("Must enter in one product!"); return;} 

          //CHECKS FOR FLOATS IN Quantity FIELD
          else if (Math.floor(test) != Math.ceil(test)) { alert("Cannot have float quantities!"); return; } 
          else { 
                //My attempt at coding a block that captures the product 
                //Number, and the quantity selected. Is there a way 
                /* QUESTION */
                array.push(i); array.push(x) 
           }
        }
        if (x == 0) { alert("Must have at least one product quantity to continue!"); return; }
        else { alert("good!"); } 
    }}

    </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```